# With probability one, the function $t \mapsto B_t$ is nowhere differentiable.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

The context is that we have a theorem about Brownian motion which says that with probability one, the function $t \mapsto B_t$ is nowhere differentiable.

I am confused about what it means by a function $t \mapsto B_t$. It seems like it refers to the Brownian motion $B_t$, but to me it also seems like a function that sends $t$ to a function space, i.e. $$f: \mathbb R \to \text{a function space}$$. Am I right?
How is the open set defined in this function space? $L^p$ norm? Could you help to explain that with a concrete example?

Comment: Let $P$ be the Wiener measure on $C[0,\infty)$. Then $P(f \text{ is somewhere differentiable})=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ can be thought of as a collection of normal random variables $B_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ satisfying certain conditions like independent and stationary increments and almost surely continuous trajectories.

What do that last condition - and the event you asked about - mean?

Let
$$A=\{\omega : t\mapsto B_t(\omega) \text{ is nowhere differentiable.} \}$$
be the event in question.

For every fixed $\omega$, $t\mapsto B_t(\omega)$ defines a trajectory, a function $B_{\bullet}(\omega):[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ like usual. For this function, it can be tested whether the claim is true or not.

Then the set of $\omega$ with non-differentiable trajectories will be an event for which we will be able to compute its probabiltiy, and it will turn out to be $1$.

As further intuition, when people graph Brownian motion they are graphing for a fixed $\omega$ one of said trajectories, which defines a curve on the line (or on space if it is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion). The following is an example graph of a Brownian trajectory $t\mapsto B_t(\omega)$, where the $x$ axis is time $t$ and the $y$ axis is the position on the line:

[image: Brownian Motion]

The same tratment that event $A$ got applies for other events, which could provide other concrete examples as well - a first one is
$$C=\{\omega : t\mapsto B_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous.}\}.$$

For a last concrete examples we may look at processes indexed in discrete time instead. If $(X_n)_n$ is a Markov process with state space $\mathbb{N}_0$ measuring a pile of coins' height, with transition probability $P$ with $P_{i,i+1}=\frac{1}{i+1}$ and $P_{i,0}=1-\frac{1}{i+1}$ for $i\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and initial state $0$, the event
$$\{\omega : n\mapsto X_n(\omega) \text{is increasing}\}$$
can be thought of in a similar manner as well.

Comment: Thank you for adding information about $\omega$, which makes the definition clearer to me now. Could you provide a real life example where we have different values of $\omega$? Maybe a stock example? What is the sample space?

Comment: When we say that $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is continuous, do we mean that $B_t(\omega)$ is continuous? Then, to prove $B_t(\omega)$ is continuous, we need to show $B_t(\omega)^{-1}(Y) \in \Sigma$ for every $Y \in \mathcal B$.

Comment: The sample space is something we *suppose* exists when we model situations in real life by using these processes. We would say that the concrete things we are seeing are the result of one fixed $\omega$ from all possible in $\Omega$. $\Omega$ the state space is usually thought of as all possible outcomes that make sense for a certain experiment, activity or process - however, for the mathematics we usually mostly care about the probability measure and not any concrete choice of $\Omega$, because we don't really know it.

Comment: We do care about $\Omega$ to show formal existance of a process or random variable. Sometimes it could also make our understanding esier to work with a concrete version of $\Omega$. For example, a more concrete version of $\Omega$ for the discrete example could be $$\Omega=\{(x_n)_n \subseteq \mathbb{N}_0 : x_{n+1}=x_n + 1 \text{ or } x_{n+1}=0\},$$ but $$\Omega_2 = \mathbb{N}_{0}^{\mathbb{N}}$$ could also be used if we define the associated probability measures accordingly.

Comment: Yes! For Brownian motion it is required that with probability one the trajectories are continuous, so there would be nothing to prove if you already know your process has that law. But if one were to want to prove that a process is a Brownian motion then showing that $B_{\bullet}(\omega)^{-1}(U)$ is open for all $U$ open could be a way to do it. You could look at the Kolmogorov continuity theorem if you want to see more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem?wprov=sfla1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following explanation helpful in helping me to understand the definition of Brownian motion.

> There are two ways to think of $\omega$ in the definition of brownian motion $B_\omega(t)$. One is to think of $\omega$ as the Brownian motion path. A random experiment is performed, and its outcome is the path of the Brownian motion. Then $B_\omega(t)$ is the value of this
> path at time $t$, and this value of course depends on which path resulted from the random experiment. Alternatively, one can think of $\omega$ as something more primitive than the path itself, akin to the outcome of a sequence of coin tosses, although now the coin is being tossed "infinitely fast." Once the sequence of coin tosses has been performed and the result $\omega$ obtained, then the path of the Brownian motion can be drawn. If the tossing is done again and a different $\omega$ is obtained, then a different path will be drawn. (Steve Shreve, *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II*)

In the Original text, $B_\omega(t)$ is written as $W(t)$. For clearity, I changed $W(t)$ to $B_\omega(t)$.